# Bigquery Loads Partial Data

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

In the last 2 weeks, we suffer from a main severe issue. 
The files upload to the bucket successfully, and exists in the cloud storage folder, but Big Query can not find them (and raises Not Found URIs error). Either, Big Query founds the batch folder, but gets only partial data from the files. It looks like it doesn't get the whole files list, when it tries to get the files from GCS.

Those problems, especially the partial loading from the Google Cloud Storage, make Big Query load mechanism to be seen unreliable.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Although very rarely, but yes, we too have observed this behaviour. We have setup an object change notification service to monitor a bucket for any new files added to it. This triggers an app engine endpoint, and app-engine endoint create a row into cloudSQL table for this particular added file. A separate service which polls this cloudSQL table containing entries for added files pulls those files one by one and loads to bigquery. But sometimes, that file not found error occurs, and file is actually not present in GCS. This is occurs very rarely though for us

Comment: In our case the files present in GCS. But BigQuery can't find it.
If we running the same loading command on the same files after x time duration it's work. The duration is not fixed and can be change, 1 minutes to 30..or even more ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gogole Big Query - Loading File From GCS Failed with "Not Found", but the file exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41207655/gogole-big-query-loading-file-from-gcs-failed-with-not-found-but-the-file-e)

Comment: Does the error persist if you wait for 10-15 minutes after loading the file into GCS?

Comment: Seems to be an issue with GCS and inconsistent results from object listing for multi-regional buckets in the US. Monitoring at 
https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/storage/16036

Comment: Thanks Felipe! The problem that it's not something new
https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=738&can=1&sort=-id&start=100
And the Multi Region Bucket is used since it was the only option at the create time of it..
If Regional Bucket is the only option that works well, they should update the all customers.